# When is a via ssh accessible remote machine considered secure?

Tags: ssh, security

To start; I'm not completely sure, if this is the correct Exchange site for this question, but I couldn't find a better one - so I'll ask it here anyways.

Recently i started to think about the **security of ssh**.
I have an **Ubuntu VM** (or any other linux distr.) running on a server, to which i can connect via ssh. To start securing the remote machine, I started using **public/private keys** for the authentication.

As a further step, I thought of **disabling the root login** - which has a 24 char long generated password.

My Questions now are:

- Do I even need to disable root login with such a password?
- Is this enough to make my remote machine secure? If no;
- What other steps should I take to secure my remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this enough to make my remote machine secure?**

This is the wrong question. There is no total security, security is always relative.

Is it "secure enough"? Maybe, but why not add more security even if it's "secure enough".

**What other steps should I take to secure my remote machine?**

- Disable password login completely, then you don't need to care even if 24 random chars might be fine as a password, it's still much less secure than key-based authentication.
- Use a non-standard port. While this doesn't help for targeted attacks, it will eliminate >99% of random / automized attacks. Even if your passwords are good and the attacks won't do any "real harm", it will spam your log files and you might miss real issues.
- Use port knocking.
- Use `fail2ban`. This will make attacks a lot more difficult, however as attacks are usually coming from botnets with many IPs, it has still only limited affect.
- Limit users permissions to the minimum necessary.
- Use a firewall to limit connections by IP (range) if possible.
- Consider: security of your server is not only `ssh`. Any service exposed to the internet can be attacked, so some measures could be:

  - Let each service run with a  different, unprivileged user
  - Use containers/virtual machines to separate processes.
  - Use a firewall to allow access only to ports that are needed for your services
  - Keep all software up to date at any time.
  - Follow security bulletins for the software you're using.

Check [this similar question and answers on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-methods-are-available-for-securing-ssh) for more information.